# Documenting a function with phpDocumentor's @since tag

Tags: php, phpdoc

I have a function `my_function()` in my project that I'd like to rename in my next release. My project is currently at version 1.0 so my next release will be 1.1.

```
/**
 * Summary
 *
 * @since 1.0
 */
function my_function() {
    // Stuff.
}
```

As you can see in the example above, I'm documenting my code with [phpDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/) docblocks. If I go ahead and change the name of this function, should I increment the @since tag to 1.1? I'm trying to understand if a function name change would mean that function is seen as a new element. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function's name will be changed, this will be **another** function. 
And users of your api or whatever should rewrite their codes, as previous function will be not supported anymore. So for a new function you should change @since attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Out of interest, if I kept the function name the same but changed the number of parameters it accepts from 1 to zero, would that mean an update to the @since tag is needed?

Comment: According to http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/since.html#examples you can add another `@since` tag with description what has changed.